# How to access DOM of web page through button click on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, dom

I am creating Chrome extension and I have code like this:

```
this.load = function () {
    var self = this;
    var formElements = new FormElements(self._getUrl());
    var haveInputs = false;
    $('input, select, textarea').each(
        function (index) {
            var input = $(this);
            var inputElement = new InputElement(input.attr('id'), input.attr('name'), input.val());

            formElements.insertElement(inputElement);
            haveInputs = true;
        }
    );
    if (haveInputs) {           
        self._FormElementsArray.push(formElements);
    }
}
```

I am calling this function load on button click in chrome extension, but this jQuery code won't read DOM from web page instead it's reading Chrome extension DOM, so my question is how to manipulate DOM of web page through jQuery on button click in Chrome extension?

Comment: are you loading jquery in your extension ?

Comment: Yes, I am loading it in my extension. Should I load it like content scripts, I tried that also, but couldn't achieve button click call of the this.load function from extension?